# Is there any way to filtering the queryset dynamicaly in django forms for a foreignkey correct?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a form for this model

```py
class SemAssign(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.staff.username}'
```

and my `forms.py` looks like

```py
class SemAssignForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SemAssign
        fields = ['staff','semester']
```

And i made a queryset based on a user-defined filter as in my `views.py`

```py
def assign_sem(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        dept = request.GET.get('department')
        sem = request.GET.get('semester')
        form=SemAssignForm(request.POST)
        #form.fields['staff'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True, profile__Department=dept)
        #form.fields['semester'].queryset = Subject.objects.filter(sem=sem)

        if form.is_valid():
            SemAssign=form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
```

When the query works perfectly the form is validated as wrong. And if i don't make query the form is validated successfully. I'm sure i missing somewhere in querying the foreignkey set. Can anyone sought me that?

My friend suggested me with modelformset, but that is not my scope. I just want to filter the fields of `SemAssign` models based on a `GET` request filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the code for creating the form and handling the submitted form.  Usually the first is a GET and the second is a POST.  So something like this:

```
def assign_sem(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Your code to create the form and set the right querysets
    elif request.method == 'POST'::
        # Your code to check that the submitted form is valid and save it
```